# What do Flags and Reqs mean in uTorrent?

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent

I'm seeding a torrent file in uTorrent, and under **Peers** tab it shows the following statistics:

[image: 01]
[image: 02]

What do those **Flags** (some combinations of upper and lower case letters like u, h, i, x, e, p) mean? Secondly, what does **Reqs** (0|5, 0|7, 0|11, etc.) mean? It's not visible for every peer and its value changes every second.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

The meanings of the flags used to be given in [the uTorrent FAQ](https://web.archive.org/web/20141111072948/http://www.utorrent.com/help/faq/misc#faq13) (archived link):

> - D = Currently downloading (interested and not choked)
> - d = Your client wants to download, but peer doesn't want to send (interested and choked)
> - U = Currently uploading (interested and not choked)
> - u = Peer wants your client to upload, but your client doesn't want to (interested and choked)
> - O = Optimistic unchoke
> - S = Peer is snubbed
> - I = Peer is an incoming connection
> - K = Peer is unchoking your client, but your client is not interested
> - ? = Your client unchoked the peer but the peer is not interested
> - X = Peer was included in peerlists obtained through Peer Exchange (PEX) or an IPv6 peer told you its IPv4 address.
> - H = Peer was obtained through [DHT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_hash_table).
> - E = Peer is using Protocol Encryption (all traffic)
> - e = Peer is using Protocol Encryption (handshake)
> - P = Peer is using [uTorrent uTP](https://web.archive.org/web/20130924061703/http://www.utorrent.com/help/documentation/utp)
> - L = Peer is local (discovered through network broadcast, or in reserved local IP ranges)

The numbers in the `Reqs` column show how many pieces you have requested from the peer, and how many the peer has requested from you.

Comment: Regarding the `Reqs` column: It's not *pieces*, it's how many *(16KB) chunks* that is active in the request queue currently.

Answer (score 41):

<sup>*I know this has been answered, but the previous answers aren't as exhaustive (a few more flags listed here, such as `h` and `F`, as well as `T` from Transmission, which is equivalent to `P` in µTorrent.)*</sup>

µTorrent divides flags into two groups, meanings are the same regardless of grouping. Note that flag capitalization *does* matter.

**µTorrent Group #1:**

> - `D` = Currently downloading *(interested, unchoked)*
> - `d` = Your client wants to download, but peer doesn't want to send *(interested, choked)*
> - `U` = Currently uploading *(interested, unchoked)*
> - `u` = Peer wants your client to upload, but your client doesn't want to *(interested, choked)*
> - `S` = Peer is snubbed *(unchoked, but request timed out)*

**µTorrent Group #2:**

> - `?` = Your client unchoked the peer but the peer is not interested
> - `E` = Peer is using Protocol Encryption *(all traffic)*
> - `e` = Peer is using Protocol Encryption *(handshake only)*
> - `F` = Peer was involved in a hashfailed piece *(not necessarily a bad peer, just involved)*
> - `H` = Peer was obtained through DHT
> - `h` = Peer connection established via UDP hole-punching
> - `I` = Peer is an incoming connection *(peer initiated connection, not you)*
> - `K` = Peer unchoked your client, but your client is not interested
> - `L` = Peer is local *(discovered via network broadcast, or in reserved local IP ranges)*
> - `O` = Optimistic unchoke *(was choked and is now getting a "second-chance")*
> - `P` = Peer is using uTP *(UDP-based transport, instead of the default TCP)*
> - `X` = Peer was included in peerlists obtained through Peer Exchange *(PEX)*

**Transmission:**

> - `T` = Peer is using uTP *(UDP-based transport, instead of the default TCP)*

*<sub>Adding this here due to a comment by [Cobra_Fast](https://superuser.com/users/69555/cobra-fast).</sub>*

Comment: So what does the `T` flag mean? I see it on many peers very frequently.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast that the peer is using the uTP protocol

Answer (score 1):

If you check the Flags tab in utorrent you can find lots of alphabets. This what they mean:

D = Currently downloading (interested and not choked)

d = Your client wants to download, but peer doesn't want to send (interested and choked)

U = Currently uploading (interested and not choked)

u = Peer wants your client to upload, but your client doesn't want to (interested and choked)

O = Optimistic unchoke

S = Peer is snubbed

I = Peer is an incoming connection

K = Peer is unchoking your client, but your client is not interested

? = Your client unchoked the peer but the peer is not interested

X = Peer was included in peerlists obtained through Peer Exchange (PEX) or an IPv6 peer told you its IPv4 address.

H = Peer was obtained through DHT.

E = Peer is using Protocol Encryption (all traffic)

e = Peer is using Protocol Encryption (handshake)

P = Peer is using uTorrent uTP

L = Peer is local (discovered through network broadcast, or in reserved local IP ranges)

Comment: This is just a copy  of an earlier answer.