# Why is the I flag relevant in bittorrent?

Tags: bittorrent

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/562970/291007) covers the meaning of bittorrent flags, including

> I = Peer is an incoming connection (peer initiated connection, not you)

In what scenarios is this useful to know?

Answer (score 3):

This means that your client is fully connectable and can communicate with all other peers in the swarm.

A client that can't receive incoming connections are limited to only communicate with peers that are fully connectable.

However there is a exception, if there always is a `h` together with the `I`, then the client can only receive incoming connections via UDP hole-punching.

> `h` = Peer connection established via UDP hole-punching